# Remove AjaxEventBehavior after execution

Tags: wicket

I have the following `AjaxEventBehavior` that is added to a specific component, but actually adds a listener to the whole page.

```
Behavior b = new AjaxEventBehavior("keydown") {
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        // Here I'm adding a AjaxCallListener overriding getPrecondition to only activate if a certain key was pressed. Probably not that important for this example.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // Here I remove (effectively the component is replaced with a empty WebMarkupContainer and not set to invisible) the component the behavior was added to. I know it's a bad solution, but there is no real way around it for me.
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence getCallbackScript(Component component) {
        // This is where it gets ugly. Instead of rendering the callbackScript for the component it was added to I want to add it to "window". That's why i use "getPage()" instead of "component".
        CharSequence ajaxAttributes = renderAjaxAttributes(getPage());
        return "Wicket.Ajax.ajax(" + ajaxAttributes + ")"
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, that the event is still registered even after execution. So if the event occurs a second time it automatically forwards to a Access Denied"-page probably because the event still has some reference to a old page.

In theory just removing the event after execution should be enough, but I just can't figure out how to do it. But maybe  there is also a better alternative than this to add a AjaxEvent to `window` or `document` that won't cause this problem. I know that usually you can just add the event to the page instead, but in this case I would also have to add the whole page to another AjaxRequestTarget just to get a few lines of  JS to run.

Comment: How about using an event namespace "keydown.globalfancy" and removing the listener in your precondition with jQuery(e.target).off(".globalfancy")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unregister the event listener after the execution. There are several places where you could do this:

- in Java

  @Override
  protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
  // ...
  target.appendJavaScript("jQuery(window).off('keydown')");
  }
- in JavaScript

  - as @svenmeier suggested in the precondition script
  - in the `complete/success/failure` scripts

  jQuery(attrs.c).off(attrs.e);